# How to seperate data after comma and save it in different columns of excel using python

Tags: python, excel, database

I have data in the format below:

| Phone No | DTMF Input |
| --- | --- |
| 9999912345 | 1,1,2 |
| 9999912345 | 2,1,2 |

I want to convert it into this format

| Phone No | Ques 1 | Ques 2 | Ques 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9999912345 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 9999912345 | 2 | 1 | 2 |

I could only split data using
**df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns= ['DTMF'])**

Please help me to organise this data

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?
This is the data in excel sheet.

[image: Data in Excel]

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel (r'path/to/file.xlsx')
new_df=df.values.tolist()
for lists in new_df:
    lists[1]=lists.extend(lists[1].split(","))
    lists.remove(None)
new_data=pd.DataFrame(new_df,columns=["Phone no","Q1","Q2","Q3"]) 
print(new_data)
new_data.to_excel(r'path/to/file.xlsx',index=False)
```

Output:

```
     Phone no Q1 Q2 Q3
0  9999912345  1  1  2
1  9999912345  2  1  2
```

This is the output after exporting it to excel. In case you get any scientific notation, just double click on that cell.

[image: Image After exporting]